# Same value returned by 2 object with same Mocked Interfaces using JMockit

Tags: java, jmockit

I made a simple Test Class to simplify my actual problem :

public class BidonTest {

```
@Mocked
IBidon ibidon;

@Mocked
IBidon ibidon2;

@Mocked
Bidon bidon;

@Mocked
Bidon bidon2;

@Test
public void testBidon(){
    new NonStrictExpectations(2, Bidon.class){
        {
            ibidon.doIt(); result = "i: coco";
            ibidon2.doIt(); result = "i: ismael et jordan";
            bidon.doIt(); result = "c: coco";
            bidon2.doIt(); result = "c: ismael et jordan";
        }
    };
    System.out.println(ibidon.doIt());
    System.out.println(ibidon2.doIt());
    System.out.println(bidon.doIt());
    System.out.println(bidon2.doIt());
}


public interface IBidon{
    public String doIt();
}

public class Bidon implements IBidon{
    @Override
    public String doIt(){
        return "toto";
    }
}
```

}

Below, the test result :

```
i: coco
i: coco
c: coco
c: ismael et jordan
```

My first question is : why ibidon2 returns "coco" ? (even if i have few ideas, but maybe someone here is a JMockit expert :D )
My second question is : how can i change it to make it return "ismael et jordan" ?

Comment: It should be just `new NonStrictExpectations()`. The `int` parameter is only for iterated recording of expectations, while the parameter which accepts a `Class` literal is only for *dynamic partial mocking* (in this case, the `Bidon` class is already mocked through the two mock fields).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me, after fixing your source.

```
package main;

import mockit.Mocked;
import mockit.NonStrictExpectations;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestBidon {
    @Mocked IBidon ibidon;
    @Mocked IBidon ibidon2;
    @Mocked Bidon bidon;
    @Mocked Bidon bidon2;

    @Test public void testBidon() {
        new NonStrictExpectations() {{
            ibidon.doIt();  result = "i: coco";
            ibidon2.doIt(); result = "i: ismael et jordan";
            bidon.doIt();   result = "c: coco";
            bidon2.doIt();  result = "c: ismael et jordan";
        }};

        System.out.println(ibidon.doIt());
        System.out.println(ibidon2.doIt());
        System.out.println(bidon.doIt());
        System.out.println(bidon2.doIt());
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
i: coco
i: ismael et jordan
c: coco
c: ismael et jordan
```

What version are you using? The above was via 0.999.12.

(Also not sure why you're using an invocation count here since it depends on being a `NonStrictInvocation` to avoid the assert.)

Comment: I'm currntly using the jmockit 0.999.3.

Comment: @TerriJordan Can you upgrade to the current version and try again?

Comment: I'll try to upgrade the version and post the result then.

Comment: @TerriJordan I thought your code was initially missing a pair of curly-brackets (`"{}"`), but maybe it was a cut-and-paste error somehow.

Comment: You were right, it was a version problem, issue fixed with an upgrade.

Comment: This solution is not longer working with version 1.9 of jmockit. It shows the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is already mocked: class com.dvag.ki.pim.aufgaben.store.BideonTest$Bidon
 at com.dvag.ki.pim.aufgaben.store.BideonTest$1.<init>...